# Headset-Microphone is detected but not working?

Tags: 16.04, sound, lubuntu, microphone

I just bought a brand-new set of headphones & mic headset, but for some reason the mic just isn't actually receiving any signals.

[image]

I have already tried fiddling with PulseAudio & pavucontrol, checking every setting on `alsamixer`, restarting my laptop, and reading every question regarding this sort of problem on this website (and others, of course). Any suggestions?

Here are all the specs:

- Headset: Philips SHE3905
- Laptop: Toshiba Chromebook 2 (CB35-B3340)
- Distro Version: Lubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS)

Comment: Have you read http://askubuntu.com/tags/sound/info? Please provide all the data. Also is it a Crouton or native installation on the Chromebook?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @bcmcfc No but the situation I needed it for was resolved (a few months ago).